# How much electric charge can a copper sphere, made of N atoms, contain?

Tags: electrostatics

If somebody wants to charge a cooper sphere made of N atoms, what is the maximum positive charge the sphere can reach? Same question about a negative charge.

[image]

[Source](https://search.yahoo.com/yhs/search?p=copper+structur&ei=UTF-8&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-001)

For example if the sphere is small, made of 100 - 1000 atoms, can all atoms remain without the electron on the last layer or even without some electrons from the deeper layers?

Note: *The indicated answer is for the case when someone wants to charge the sphere with a negative charge and it contain just a qualitative explanation.*

Comment: Hi Robert. We encourage site members to [do a quick search to see if their question has already been asked](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=maximum+charge+sphere). If the (obviously related) question I've linked doesn't give you then answer you want perhaps you could edit your question to indicate what speficially hasn't been addressed by the previous question.

Comment: The answer you indicated is for the case when someone wants to charge the sphere with a negative charge and it contain just a qualitative explanation.

Comment: Are you specifically asking about particles of copper small enough that we can no longer consider them as having the bulk properties of the metal?

Comment: Is there a formula that gives the maximum quantity of charge (negative or positive) a cooper sphere of radius $R$ can reach? The formula can be for a microscopic or macroscopic sphere.

Comment: This is why we need a "what-if.xkcd" tag.

Comment: For large spheres the limit is the charge blowing the whole thing apart, not each atom's ability to lose an electron. The charges will concentrate to the edge and try to pull on the metal outward.